Android studio insert mongodb realm
This is my code at android studio
val myDoc = Document().apply {
                    append("name", "futureTech")
                    append("video", "youtube")
                    append("startdate", "2003")
                }
findViewById<Button>(R.id.button).setOnClickListener {
                    lifecycleScope.launch {
                        try {
                            val result = user.functions.call<String>("insertFunction", myDoc)
                            Log.i("TAG", "Function result: $result")
                        } catch (e: Exception) {
                            Log.e("TAG", "Error calling function: ${e.message}", e)
                        }
                    }
                }`


And this is the "insertFunction" code
exports = async function(doc) {
  if (typeof doc !== 'object' || doc === null) {
    throw new Error("Invalid argument: Argument must be an object.");
  }

  const collection = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("projectTest").collection("insertUser");

  try {
    const result = await collection.insertOne(doc);
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Error inserting document:", e);
    throw new Error("Failed to insert document.");
  }
};


I want to add a piece of data to my database, but the error keeps showing up.
Error calling function: [Service][FunctionExecutionError(4313)] {"message":"Failed to insert document.","name":"Error"}. io.realm.kotlin.mongodb.exceptions.FunctionExecutionException: [Service] [FunctionExecutionError(4313)] {"message":"Failed to insert document.","name":"Error"}.
I'd like to ask for help. Is there any way to solve it?
I had change my data describe into
val myDoc = mapOf(
                    "name" to "futureTech",
                    "video" to "youtube",
                    "startdate" to "2003"
                )


but it didn't work
